# onkey only only fires once

Tags: excel, vba

I want to re-map the numpad decal key to a colon. it's close to working but only fires once.
from everything I've read, i was under the impression that if i assign a key to a sub() it stays that way until it is re-assigned again. do i need an endless loop?

i put this in the worksheet that i want the key remapped in:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
Application.OnKey "{110}", "colonb"   ' numpad decmal
MsgBox "hello"
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Deactivate()
 Application.OnKey "{110}"            
 MsgBox "bye"
End Sub
```

and this in the module of the workbook:

```
Sub colonb()

MsgBox ("???")
Application.SendKeys (":")
Sendkeys "{NUMLOCK}", True
End Sub
```

if i go to the sheet i get the "hello" and it will send 1 ":" then its back to a decimal
when i go to a different sheet i get the "bye" and its back to a decal as intended.

I gave it a good fight, the CPU is winning. I would use Autohotkey for this but I can't install it on
the company computer.

Thank you

Comment: According to Microsoft *There is currently no way to detect the command key in current versions of Office VBA. Microsoft is aware of this and is looking into it.*  https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/api/excel.application.onkey

Answer (score 0):

You indicate that you can do what you need with AutoHotkey, but cannot install it on your work computer... are you able to run executables?
If so, you may be able to compile your AutoHotkey script into an .exe and run it from a thumb drive or some other option?

Comment: I cant. I get prompted for an admin password. Good answer though, thank you